# Let $f$ and $g $ be continuous function where $g(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(y)(y-x)dy$. If $g$ is 3 times continuously differentiable, what about $f$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Question 53 from [practice test](https://www.ets.org/s/gre/pdf/practice_book_math.pdf):

Let f and g be continuous real functions such that $g(x) = \int_{0}^{x}f(y)(y-x)dy$. If g is 3 times continuously differentiable, what is the greatest integer n for which f is n times continuously differentiable?

I find that $g'(x) = x f(x) - x I(x)$ with  $I(x) = \int_{0}^{x}f(y)dy$ which leads me to think that $g'$ being $C^2$, $f is c2$, but actually the answer is 1. Where am I wrong?

Comment: I don't see why there are any constraints on $f$ at all. For example, can't we choose $f = \sin$ and then $f$ is infinitely differentiable?

Comment: Oh I think I misinterpreted. $g$ can only be differentiated 3 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$g(x) = \int_0^x f(y)(y-x)dy$$
$$=\int_0^x f(y)ydy - \int_0^x f(y)xdy$$

Taking first derivative
$$ D_x[\int_0^x f(y)ydy - \int_0^x f(y)xdy]$$

$$ =D_x[\int_0^x f(y)ydy - x\int_0^x f(y)dy]$$
$$ =D_x[\int_0^x f(y)ydy] - D_x[x\int_0^x f(y)dy]$$
$$ =xf(x) - (\int_0^xf(y)dy + xf(x))$$
$$ = - \int_0^xf(y)dy $$

Taking another derivative
$$ D_x[ - \int_0^xf(y)dy ]$$
$$= -f(x)$$

So we have
$$ g''(x) = -f(x)$$

So since the left hand side is differentiable, so is the right hand side.

That shows $f$ is at least once differentiable. And if the fourth derivative of $g$ does not exist, then neither does the second derivative of $f$.

Comment: Repetition here: $$ =D_x[\int_0^x f(y)ydy] - D_x[x\int_0^x f(y)dy]$$
$$ =D_x[\int_0^x f(y)ydy] - D_x[x\int_0^x f(y)dy]$$

Comment: Could you double check? You write $D_x(x \int_{0}^{x}f) = \int_{0}^{x}f + xf(x)$ but I think that's wrong (see my guess for this in the question)

Comment: @Thomas this is application of product rule with $x \times \int_0^x f dy$

Comment: you are right, I don't know how I made this mistake. thanks!